# How can I know an undecorated JFrame has been fully painted on the screen?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a simple code like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle maximizeRectangle=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().
        getMaximumWindowBounds();
        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();

        //frame1
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setUndecorated(true);
        frame1.setBounds(maximizeRectangle);
        JPanel cp1 = new JPanel();
        cp1.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
        JButton but1 = new JButton("I'm frame 1");
        cp1.add(but1);
        ActionListener ac1 = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                //here is my question:
                //how can I know when frame2 has been fully painted? and then I can 
                //set visibility of frame1 to false to avoid flickering
                frame1.setVisible(false);
            }
        };
        but1.addActionListener(ac1);
        frame1.setContentPane(cp1);

        //frame2
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2.setUndecorated(true);
        frame2.setBounds(maximizeRectangle);
        JPanel cp2 = new JPanel();
        cp2.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
        JButton but2 = new JButton("I'm frame 2");
        cp2.add(but2);
        ActionListener ac2 = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame1.setVisible(true);
                //here is my question:
                //how can I know when frame1 has been fully painted? and then I can 
                //set visibility of frame2 to false to avoid flickering
                frame2.setVisible(false);
            }
        };
        but2.addActionListener(ac2);
        frame2.setContentPane(cp2);

        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

when I press buttons, I can see flickers(desktop background). how can I know a JFrame has been fully painted on the screen before I set visibility of another JFrame to false?

when I press buttons, I can see flickers(desktop background). how can I know a JFrame has been fully painted on the screen before I set visibility of another JFrame to false?

**I can't use timer solution!**

Many thanks

Comment: You cannot. Could you explain, what you want to achieve? Probably we can propose you another solution.

Comment: I really want to solve that flicker without using timers(because it depends on system performance) is there any solution?

Comment: Why you want to use second frame? You can simply change content of the first. See the about [Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: I tried adding `Thead.sleep(1000);` in the `actionPerformed` method. The flickering problem still persists however.

Even after the second frame has been fully painted, the flickering happens at this code: `frame1.setVisible(false);`

Comment: @Kcits: Yes, the only solution I can think is to know when JFrame has been fully painted on the screen but I don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: No, I think you misunderstood my comment. Knowing if the JFrame is fully painted doesn't help. The flickering happens when your set the visibility of the previous frame to FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

I've rewrite youre example without second frame and corresponding flickering. As I already mentioned in my comment, you should use `CardLayout` instead of second frame.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
public class Test {
    private static final String FRAME1 = "frame1";

    private static final String FRAME2 = "frame2";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Test::startUp);
    }

    private static void startUp() {
        Rectangle maximizeRectangle = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
        CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
        frame1.setLayout(cl);

        // frame1
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setUndecorated(true);
        frame1.setBounds(maximizeRectangle);
        JPanel cp1 = new JPanel();
        cp1.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
        JButton but1 = new JButton("I'm frame 1");
        cp1.add(but1);
        ActionListener ac1 = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cl.show(frame1.getContentPane(), FRAME2);
            }
        };
        but1.addActionListener(ac1);
        frame1.add(cp1, FRAME1);

        // frame2
        JPanel cp2 = new JPanel();
        cp2.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
        JButton but2 = new JButton("I'm frame 2");
        cp2.add(but2);
        ActionListener ac2 = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cl.show(frame1.getContentPane(), FRAME1);
            }
        };
        but2.addActionListener(ac2);
        frame1.add(cp2, FRAME2);

        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Medvynskyy: many thanks for your reply; but I think I couldn't say my real intention. in fact, I want to 
maximize a JFrame according to this code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle maximizeRectangle=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().
        getMaximumWindowBounds();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getRootPane().setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 10));

        JButton but1 = new JButton("Maximize");
        ActionListener ac1 = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setBounds(maximizeRectangle);
            }
        };
        but1.addActionListener(ac1);

        JButton but2 = new JButton("Minimize");
        ActionListener ac2 = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setSize(500, 500);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        };
        but2.addActionListener(ac2);

        frame.add(but1);
        frame.add(but2);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

but when I press the Maximize button, I can see a flicker at the top-left corner. of course I know why that happens:
because at first JFrame at the size (500, 500) is transformed to the location (0, 0) and then is expanded to full screen.
how can I see only full screen JFrame when I press Maximize?
my previous question was an idea for this problem.